# how do i call a protocol in one class from another in swift?

Tags: swift, model-view-controller

I have my `viewcontroller` that implements one `Protocol`,

```
import UIKit

class FirstScreenViewController: UIViewController, mainViewProtocol {

    var presenter: mainPresenterProtocol?

    //Protocol Functions
    static func showSmallHeadline(textToShow: String) {
        <#code#>
    }

    func showHeadline(textToShow: String) {
        <#code#>
    }
}
```

I have my presenter that implement second `Protocol`

```
import Foundation

class MainPresenter: mainPresenterProtocol {

    var screenViewController: mainViewProtocol?

    //confirms protocol
    static func presenterProtocolFuncOne() {
        <#code#>
    }

    func presenterProtocolFuncTwo(numOne: Int, numTwo: Int, sucssesMessage: String, failMessage: String) -> String {
        <#code#>
    }

    func presenterProtocolFucThree() -> Bool {
        <#code#>
    }
}
```

how do I call the functions in my presenter (that implements them through the `protocol`) from my `viewcontroller`, 
and how do I call the functions in my `viewcontroller` (that implements them through the `protocol`) from my presenter ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key thing here - `strong` relationship between controller and presenter. You should avoid that by adding `weak` to presenter property in controller.

```
protocol MainViewProtocol {
    func controllerProtocolFunc()
}

protocol MainPresenterProtocol: class {
    func presenterProtocolFunc()
}

class FirstScreenViewController: UIViewController, MainViewProtocol {
    weak var presenter: MainPresenterProtocol?

    func controllerProtocolFunc() { }
}


class MainPresenter: MainPresenterProtocol {
    var screenViewController: MainViewProtocol?

    func presenterProtocolFunc() { }
}
```

Next step, when you need to call presenter(controller) func from controller(presenter), simply call it with optional chaining:

```
presenter?.presenterProtocolFunc()
// or
screenViewController?.controllerProtocolFunc()
```

P.S. Also, note from [docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html#ID275):

> Because protocols are types, **begin their names with a capital letter**
>   (such as FullyNamed and RandomNumberGenerator) to match the names of
>   other types in Swift (such as Int, String, and Double).

Comment: i tried to use this code it outputs "'weak' must not be applied to non-class-bound 'MainPresenterProtocol'; consider adding a protocol conformance that has a class bound"

Comment: @ChiefMadog, it shouldn't. Did you copy the protocols? If not, you should manually add `class` to the protocol (`protocol MainPresenterProtocol: class`) that will be set as `weak`.

Comment: ok thanx managed it, 
But it looks like that i call the function in my presenter but it is never called instead i get my default value i opened a different question on that. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51964077/presenter-function-is-never-read-on-swift-3

Comment: lets see if i can make it work first, if so i'll except both of them. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Add properties to each class referencing the other object by the type of the protocol.

```
class FirstScreenViewController: UIViewController, mainViewProtocol {
    var presenter: mainPresenterProtocol?

    // rest of the code
}

class MainPresenter: mainPresenterProtocol {
    var screenViewController: mainViewProtocol?

    // rest of the code
}
```

Assign the properties after constructing both objects. The `?` after the protocol type makes them optional, allowing you delay the assignment to the point in time when both objects exist. Alternatively, you can swap out the `?` for a `!` if you are certain the properties will be assigned non-nil values, so you can save a lot of nil-checking and dereferencing.

```
let viewController = FirstScreenViewController()
let mainPresenter = MainPresenter()

viewController.presenter = mainPresenter
presenter.screenViewController = viewController
```

Comment: hi Thnx, What do you mean by assign the properties after constucting both objects ? when should i construct them ? i'ts my first app so i dont quit understnad

Comment: I added a bit of code to illustrate how to connect the objects. At some point both objects will exist (either because you created them yourself, like in the above code sample, or because you loaded them from a XIB file), and then you can connect them like so.

Comment: i don't understand, i tried to copy paste that code to my on viewdidload in my viewcontroller, and it output "Value of type 'mainPresenterProtocol?' has no member 'screenViewController'"
can u maybe give an example on where i should initlize it based on my code ?