# presenter function is never read on swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, model-view-controller

I'm calling my presenter functon that is listed in a protocol that my presenter is implementing but whenever i call it it never goes inside, 
how do i initilize my presenter so i can call the interface funcion ?

here is my view controller:

```
import UIKit

class FirstScreenViewController: UIViewController, MainViewProtocol {

    var myPresenter: MainPresenterProtocol?

    func outputPresenterFunction() {
       print (myPresenter?.presenterProtocolFuncTwo(numOne: 2, numTwo: 4, sucssesMessage: "Made it ?", failMessage: "failed :(" ) ?? "Default landed")
    }

}
```

in my presenter i have:

```
import Foundation

class MainPresenter: MainPresenterProtocol {

    var screenViewController: MainViewProtocol?

    func presenterProtocolFuncTwo(numOne: Int, numTwo: Int, sucssesMessage: String, failMessage: String) -> String {
        print("function is called")
        return "presenter function is called sussfuly"
    }

}
```

and my protocol itself:

```
protocol MainViewProtocol {
    func showSmallHeadline(textToShow: String)
    func showHeadline(textToShow: String)
}

protocol MainPresenterProtocol {
    static func presenterProtocolFuncOne()
    func presenterProtocolFuncTwo(numOne: Int, numTwo: Int, sucssesMessage: String, failMessage: String) -> String
    func presenterProtocolFucThree () -> Bool
}
```

whenever i call the presenterProtocolFuncTwo, i get my default value and it doens't go inside the function in my presenter

Comment: And how did you assign `myPresenter` a value? Where is it set in your code?

Comment: @Joakim Danielson Can you explain more ? on your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `myPresenter` and `screenViewController` properties to work with them.

```
protocol MainViewProtocol: class { ... }

class FirstScreenViewController: UIViewController, MainViewProtocol {
    var myPresenter: MainPresenterProtocol?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myPresenter = MainPresenter(controller: self)
    }
}

class MainPresenter: MainPresenterProtocol {
    weak var screenViewController: MainViewProtocol?

    init(controller: MainViewProtocol) {
        screenViewController = controller
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need assign an object to your property `myPresenter` somewhere in your code, like in viewDidLoad for example

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     myPresenter = MainPresenter()
}
```